# showing an image with css Gradiant effect

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am applying the css gradiant effect to a "th" column of table like this,

```
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white 5%,#D6DFE3);
    background: linear-gradient(top,white 5%,#D6DFE3);
```

Later i have to append a class  whose css is some thing like this one in which i want to show an image

```
.Img
{
  background-image:url(../images/asc.png);
  background-color:Green;
}
```

I am appending the **.Img class** the **th**. But the image is not showing because of the gradient effect. How can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an `<img>` tag in the `<th>` or any other tag like `<span>` or `<button>` and give it the needed background style

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue as

```
th{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white 5%,#D6DFE3);
    background: linear-gradient(top,white 5%,#D6DFE3);
}

.Img
{
  background :url(../images/asc.png),  -moz-linear-gradient(top,gray 5%,#D6DFE3) !important;
  background: url(../images/asc.png), linear-gradient(top,gray 5%,#D6DFE3) !important;

  background-position:right center !important;
  background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
}
```

The **!important** tag did the trick for me. I was able to override the behaviors with !important

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
th{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white 5%,#D6DFE3);
    background: linear-gradient(top,white 5%,#D6DFE3);
    z-index:-1;
}
.Img
{
    background-image:url(../images/asc.png);
    background-color:Green;
    z-index:1;position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: You can use `image tag` in `th`.